# SDL Tridion Sites 9 Discovery Service does not start

Tags: discovery-service, sites-9

I'm are currently in the process of installing SDL Tridion Sites 9.  During the installation of the micro services I noticed that the discovery service is not starting.  It is logging the following error:

> 2019-04-25 09:45:12,959 ERROR [main] SpringApplication - Application
>   startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceFactoryImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'dataSourceProviders'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSourceProvider':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSource': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'storageManager'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field
>   'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.ServiceContainer.main(ServiceContainer.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:24)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:41)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSourceProvider':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSource': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'storageManager'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field
>   'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1314)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>     ... 23 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSource': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'storageManager'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field
>   'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>     ... 39 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'StorageManagerImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field
>   'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>     ... 52 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'storageFactoryConfigurationLoader':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1623)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>     ... 65 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'defaultdbEntityManagerFactory': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory.configureBundle(JPADAOFactory.java:90)
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configureStorage(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:136)
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.configure(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:73)
>     at
>   com.tridion.storage.configuration.StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.initialize(StorageFactoryConfigurationLoader.java:53)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
>     ... 77 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   persistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate
>   collection persister
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
>     ... 95 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate collection
>   persister org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
>     ... 99 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/CharScanner     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:42)
>     at
>   com.sdl.delivery.service.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:31)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator.translate(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.sql.Template.translateOrderBy(Template.java:714)   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:554)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.(OneToManyPersister.java:69)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:152)
>     ... 107 common frames omitted

The weird thing is that only the discovery microservice is not able to start.   To troubleshoot this issue I have tried the following steps:

- Checked the database details;  I can login via the ODBC manager with the same database details
- Tried to start the application from the command line; result: it is starting but after a few seconds the process terminates
- Tried to run a SDL Web 8.5 Discovery service with same database details as the SDL Tridion Sites 9 Discovery Service. This works, so I can assume that the OS, JRE and database can be excluded as root cause
- Checked if the cd_storage_conf.xml is well formed

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything below this in the error log?

Comment: I tried to edit your formatting but your error message is not completely available. Can you update your error message?

Comment: I have added extra log information

Answer (score 2):

On the general principle that root causes are usually to be found lower down in the stack trace, I would start with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/CharScanner`

This probably indicates that the necessary jars are not available in your classpath. I'd suggest the following:

- Check the relevant directories and ensure the jars are present
- Check the start script, paying attention to the part that establishes the classpath
- If it's running as a Windows service, check the registry entries that govern the service start up
- Configure the service for debug logging, and check the logging for the startup phase for information about the classpath.

Comment: According the the debug cd_core.log logfile antlr-2.7.7.jar  is loaded: java.class.path = .\services\discovery-service\antlr-2.7.7.jar

Answer (score 1):

Seems the antlr-2.7.7.jar in discovery\services\discovery-service was corrupted. After replacing the jar,  the discovery service was able to startup.